# Connect to web server via Phonegap with SSL and Certificate

Tags: javascript, security, mobile, ssl, cordova

That's all about Phonegap Android and iOS application build on JS.

We have a server with method:
- Authorize(login,pass) 
which return certificate.p12 file (PKCS#12).

Also server has methods, which requires authorization with that certificate. Example on Ruby looks like that:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

pkcs12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read('<CERTIFICATE_PATH>'),'')

http.cert = pkcs12.certificate
http.key = pkcs12.key

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)

result = http.start {|http| 
    result = http.request(req)
    p result.body
}
```

But how to make that on JS? How make method call's on JS from Phonegap?

The only one solution which I have found: via plugins on Java and iOS, but i'm not sure that they will work. If yes, maybe someone have already made they?

Comment: PhoneGap runs within a browser object,  so just use a signed certificate,  they are pretty cheap i bet you can find one for less than $20.

Answer (score 0):

I use twitter's finagle and akka to connect to a webservice. You would have to learn scala and how to mix java with scala and install sbt, which would be an option if you have enough time to accommodate a learning curve. Scala also has a very good api for xml parsing.

An application configuration file would specify your security settings. It is worth exploring.

There is a lot of research and coding involved but it is worth it in the long run.