# Ruby Error reading in Certificate File with OpenSSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, certificate, pem

I am trying to do a simple
`OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("testuser.p12"))`
from irb with **ruby 1.8.7 (or 1.9.2)**, same result for both. The error I get back is `OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: nested asn1 error`

Is this a ruby issue, or does this suggest the cert itself is malformed? I've found some similar reports revolving around an amazon cert demonstrating such errors, which turned out to be the cert itself. It works in the browser though. Suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"testuser.p12" seems to be a PKCS#12 file according to the postfix. Reading PKCS#12 format as X.509 certificate format causes ASN.1 decoding error.

You should do `OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read("testuser.p12"))` instead.  If the file is protected with passphrase (it's normal), give the passphrase as the second parameter for PKCS12.new like `OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read("testuser.p12"), "pass")`

You can extract certificate and CA certificates by `PKCS12#certificate` and `PKCS12#ca_certs` methods.

```
p12 = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read("testuser.p12"), "pass")
p p12.certificate
p p12.ca_certs
```

Comment: thanks!  That did seem to be the problem.  I haven't had to deal with certs much and I was following an apparently bad example.  Your post and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167579/connect-to-web-server-via-phonegap-with-ssl-and-certificate) helped tremendously

Comment: update: it had been working just stopped and I can't figure out why.  it literally blew up between runs of a trial, and now even in irb, that p12 = OpenSSL line claims it needs 4 parameters?  Did some dependecy change in requiring 'net/https'?  What other 2 parameters could I need?  Any help greatly appreciated, this one has me perplexed!